# how to use correctly "lit"?

Tags: word-usage

is it correct to say : we're getting lit this weekend ?
lit here means enjoyable party

according to

[merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/lit-meaning-origin)

'Lit' has been a slang term meaning "intoxicated" for over a century. More recently, it has acquired the meaning "exciting," as well as a broader meaning along the lines of "excellent."

Comment: Most reasonably literate native speakers would recognise ***lit*** (or ***lit up***) as dated slang for "drunk, intoxicated", but I doubt 1 in 100 would ever have *used* it. Probably not 1 in 1000, to be honest.

Comment: I've used it, as have a number of people of my acquaintance. If you say "we're getting lit this weekend" I would take that to mean you're going to be drinking large volumes of alcohol this weekend.

Comment: I know what the slang *means*, but the only place I've heard it *used* is in a movie from 1958.  There are many, many other slang expressions for "get drunk" that are more current.  It's *possible* that it's still used in parts of the English-speaking world, but I'd wait for a native speaker to say it before using it myself.

Comment: @Andrew Do you ever read the N.Y. Times? It's used all over the world, every day, by English speaking young people.

Comment: I hear *lit* quite often from kids lately, almost always in the generic 'cool' meaning.

Comment: @Andrew People don't say "lit" as a synonym for drunk. Rather "lit" means the atmosphere is exciting and festive (and probably lots of alcohol was consumed). I could say my office's Christmas party where we all did jello shots was "lit", but I wouldn't use "lit" to describe a bar mitzvah (hopefully). It's a pretty recent term, at least for me.

Comment: @SenjougaharaHitagi I guess everything old is new again.  The slang is about a hundred years old, but that doesn't mean it can't acquire new meaning  :)

Comment: It may also be related to "light it up", as in [Raise a cup/We can light it up](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/onerepublic/lightitup.html) or [Drink it up, and then drink some more/Light it up, and let's let it blow](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/william/screamandshout.html). So if we [...go out on the town/And light it up till we burn it down](http://www.elyrics.net/read/n/nickelback-lyrics/see-you-at-the-show-lyrics.html), we could say the party is going to be "lit" I guess :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Lit*** in the modern vernacular means not only "intoxicated" (or "lit up") but has come to be a positive modifier which occupies roughly the same semantic space occupied over the years by such terms as *cool* and *groovy*, and *swingin(g)*.

This very day in the New York Times, the ["Quotation of the Day"](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/07/26/todayspaper/quotation-of-the-day-seatless-subway-cars-could-mean-more-room-for-a-floor-show.html) is:

[image]

If you use the expression as in your question, though, you will tell your listener that you (the plural *you*) intend to become intoxicated this weekend. If you want to communicate instead that the *party* will be enjoyable, you might express it as:

> **"The party this weekend is going to be *lit*."**

Answer (score 3):

If a person is getting lit, he or she is taking drugs to become intoxicated.  The listener/reader will not interpret that as him/her being exciting.

If a party is lit, I believe that would mean it's exciting.

If a party was lit, I believe that would mean it was excellent.

Comment: You can also use "lit" to simply mean awesome, just in the same way that people use(d) "cool" or "sweet" or "tight" when confirming/agreeing with something.